# Multiple IPs, one interface - How to configure outgoing connection with different IP?

Tags: iptables, ip

I have configured eth0 with 8 IP also add proper virtualhost in apache for different IP and everything works almost fine. When the script (like PHP,ruby) lauched by apache2 try to make outgoing connection (through cURL) it uses default eth0:0 IP not one related to domain (and incoming request). I'm trying to use something similar to this

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.202 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 99.99.99.244
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.202 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 99.99.99.245
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.202 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 99.99.99.247
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.202 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 99.99.99.246
```

Comment: You'll need to associate a different user which each virtual host and launch scripts as that user. Then you can use `iptables` rules to set the default source IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `--interface` switch to cURL to direct which interface it uses but you'll need to work out yourself which interface to use and pass it as a parameter from your script

> --interface 
>                 Perform  an operation using a specified interface. You can enter
>                 interface name, IP address or host name. An example  could  look
>                 like:
>
> ```
>           curl --interface eth0:1 http://www.netscape.com/
>
>          If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This may be over complicating things a little. You need to change your routing table in a way more advanced than `route` can. Instead you can use the iproute2 suite of tools. This tool comes as standard with most main line distributions.

```
ip route change 0.0.0.0/0 dev eth0 src 1.2.3.4 via 1.2.3.1
          source address you want to use -^           ^
                                     default gateway -^
```

Comment: PS. Careful with the above command you are changing your default route and if its wrong you could lose connection to the server you're working on.